# css reusable class understanding needed

Tags: html, css

I am using a 960 responsive layout from skeleton, i have their css stylesheet which i have to addon if i want to include class. After experimenting i managed to get the site i want, but not without having piles of unnecessary selections.

So for example, based on what u see my css reflect the selector .container.four.columns, that say if i add a banner class, in my css should i only do .container.banner or .container.four.columns.banner will be the best way?

Since i thought if i add a lot of reusable style classes to it the css selector will be very long if i go into each details.. Please advise as i'm trying to make my code look as clean and neat as possible but not sure the best selectors to use as when i tried shortcut like just .banner nothing happens and i must have at least .container.banner before it make the changes. Thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="content" class="container">                                
            <div class="four columns banner">
                <div id="banner_a3da" class="banner_img">
                <a href="./page_a3da.html" rel="external"><img src="page_home/banner_A3DA.jpg"></a>
                </div>                  
            </div>
            <div class="four columns banner">
                 <div id="banner_fi" class="banner_img">
                    <img src="page_home/banner_FI.jpg">
                 </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Base Grid */
    .container .four.columns                    { width: 220px; }

.banner or .container.banner or .container.four.columns.banner { width:100% }
```

Comment: You can read about **[Specificity Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** that can be important on the way you work

Answer (score 0):

Well either ways are correct, but you can use more classes to select specific object in your case. But maybe you have some .banner in .container.three.columns.banner and he is for example 50% and you wanted it to be 50%, but with .banner you will select him and you will resize it to 100%.

To resume, with single selection you may affect some elements that you didn't wanted, becouse there are more elements with that class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's just pseudo-CSS or what, but you do 'or' with a comma`,`:

```
.banner,
.container .banner,
.container .four.columns.banner { 
    width:100% 
}
```

You also had a missing space after `.container`.
Does that help?

Comment: hi there, i'm not so sure about when to use space or not.. i'm doing a responsive website like on full screen i can adjust the img src by just .container div.banner {width:50%}, then on another media query when i do the exact same thing it won't work, i have to include a img outcome - .container div.banner img {width:50%} then it would work.. do u know why it works on the former one but not the latter?

Comment: @Devon, a space in a CSS selector means "descendant".  No space means the other selector applies to the same element.